# I want to implement a while loop in python but I have this error

Tags: loops, indexing, while-loop

I'm trying to optimise a gradient descent of a function using a while loop but the loop  doesn't stop. How can I make it works please.

```
def GradDescent(y, la, nbiter,tau,f,epsilon):
x = y;
crit= np.zeros(nbiter);
xprev = 0
iter = 0
while norm(x-xprev)/norm(x) > epsilon:
    xprev = x
    x = x - tau*(x - y + la * gradTVeps(x,epsilon))
    crit[iter] = 1/2 * (norm(x-y)**2) + la * J(x,epsilon);
    iter = 1
return x,crit
nbiter = 10;
epsilon = np.logspace(-5, 0,num=5);
laTVTeq = 0.01;
SNRTVep = 0*np.ones(len(epsilon));


for i in range(0,len(epsilon)):
    tau = 1.8/(1 + laTVTeq *4/epsilon[i]);
    [xdenoised,crit] = GradDescent( y,laTVTeq, nbiter,tau,f,epsilon[i])
    SNRTVep[i] = snr(x0,xdenoised)
```